# Сортировка ассоциативного массива в JavaScript

Tags: javascript, массивы, сортировка

Есть несортированый ассоциативный массив типа:

```
{"key2": 2, "key3": 3, "key1": 1, "key4": 4}
```

Как сортировать его по значениям так, чтобы они располагались в порядке убывания? Т.е. должно получиться:

```
{"key4":4, "key3":3, "key2":2, "key1":1}
```

Comment: Чего Вы хотите этим достичь?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort?v=example

Comment: @E_p, это не сработает, потому что у автора не массив, а объект

Answer (score 1):

примерно так можно

```
let max = 0;
let maxName = "";
for (let name in ArrayName) {
    if (max < ArrayName[name]) {
        max = ArrayName[name];
        maxName = name;
    }
}
```

только это для максимума, для минимума сделать не сложно :)

Comment: кто поставил -1 прошу пояснить что не так) Спасибо

Comment: поясни, что делает твой код. и как он относится к вопросу? Что за _ArrayName_ и _salaries_?

Comment: ищет максимум из ArrayName. Не сложно его переделать для минимума, и если найти все значения по возрастанию можно получить массив в необходимом порядке(в данном случае по убыванию, но опять же, можно переделать по возрастанию)

Comment: как поиск максимума относится к сортировке ключей в объекте?

Comment: это я поставил. Это ответ на какой-то другой вопрос.

Comment: Разве нельзя отсортировать массив по убыванию, зная последовательность значений по убыванию?

Comment: @АлександрПиткевич, обрати внимание, что в вопросе речь идет об объекте, а не о массиве

Comment: "Есть несортированый ассоциативный массив типа:" Массив - это тоже объект. Я понимаю что фигурные скобки стоят, это объект, но мой код работает для такого объекта, единственное что ему нужно имя дать